# Perl Regex not working as expected

Tags: regex

Im tryin to match a digit, followed by a dot, and two digits after, followed by a W. `if($_ =~ /\d{1}\.\d{2}\W\/)/g` It does not work, ay ideas what im missing here?

Comment: Change `\W` to `W` - `\W` means any non-word character

Comment: by _followed by a W_ do you mean a literal `W`?

Answer (score 0):

Put the modifier inside the brackets.

```
if($_ =~ /\d\.\d{2}\W/g)
```

OR

```
if($_ =~ /\d\.\d{2}W/g)
```

Added two patterns since i don't know you want `\W` or `W`. NOte that `\W` is a special regex pattern which matches a non-word character. `W` matches a literal `W`.